# Losing the last token from every line of input read in

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program that reads lines of code from a file as strings then splits that string into tokens around each comma. (It is a comma seperated file).

It works for the most part but I'm losing the last token on every single line.

```
//This is function splits input strings into tokens. It takes in an input 
string
//and a delimiter character as parameters.
vector<string> tokenize(string inputString, char delimiter) {

    //the store the delimiter in local variable
    char newDelimiter = delimiter;

    //store the input string in local variable
    string newString = inputString;

    //vector of strings to store tokens.
    vector<string> tokenVector;

    //temp variable for making tokens
    string temp;

    //iterate through the string...

    for (int i = 0; i < newString.size(); ++i) {

        //...checking for specified delimiter.
        //If not present, add current character to temp string.
        if (newString.at(i) != newDelimiter) {
            temp += newString.at(i);
        }
        //if present, add temp string to vector and reset temp variable
        else
        {
            tokenVector.push_back(temp);
            temp = "";
        }
    }

    return tokenVector;
}

int main() {

    //string variable input will store each line of input
    string input;

    //use getline initially to "skip" the header line
    getline(cin, input);

    //this vector will be used to store each input lines string tokens
    vector<string> stringTokens;

    //this while loop will execute as long as cin is reading lines from the 
    file
    while (getline(cin, input)) {

        //print out each original line for testing purposes
        cout << input << endl;

        //split the string into tokens around commas
        stringTokens = tokenize(input, ',');

        //TEST OUTPUT
        for (int j = 0; j < stringTokens.size(); ++j) {
            cout << stringTokens.at(j) << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

A sample line of output: THere is a zero missing from the second line. The first line is simply the original string, the second the output:

```
1,000010007,01,XX,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,01 - XXXXX,XXXXXXXXXX,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

1 000010007 01 XX 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 01 - XXXXX XXXXXXXXXX 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

How shall I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the shown code. Therefore the problem must be with the code that's not shown. It's somewhat unlikely that anyone will be able to tell you what's the problem with the code that you didn't show. Just because a C++ program crashes at a particular line doesn't mean that's where the bug is. C++ does not work this way. This is why stackoverflow.com's [help] tells you that all questions of the kind "why does this program not work" must provide a code sample that meeds all requirements for a [mcve], that anyone can run themselves to reproduce the bug.

Comment: This program gets a string as input, then passes it to that function along with a delimiter of the users choice. Edit: I guess what I'm saying is that  could show you the getline statement if you'd like.

Comment: Can you post the whole code please?

Comment: No, don't post "the whole code". stackoverflow.com is not a debugging service. Post a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help]. You did read stackoverflow.com's [help], before posting your question, right? If not, why not? Unfortunately, "This program gets a string as input, then passes it to that function along with a delimiter of the users choice" is not a valid C++ program, that meets all requirements for a [mcve], that a C++ compiler can compile and produce a program that anyone can run and reproduce the problem.

Comment: I understand what Sam is saying, I'll try to post more...

Comment: I'm really sorry guys, been working at this awhile and I'm tired. I'm not getting an out of bounds error with that code. I AM losing the last token however.

Comment: What was producing the out of bounds error was when I changed i < newString.size() to i <= newString.size()

Comment: Write it as a function, specify the input string and what you expect. It will be pretty easy to fix. That's why they ask for [mcve], because you generally fix it yourself once you are forced to isolate the problem. It becomes fairly obvious. Also because we can't advise you on "other stuff" not shown. I mean, I could guess that on the last token, you set temp but never use it because you exit the loop, but ... I don't know :)

Comment: it is a function. I'll post the whole thing.

Comment: Wow. Kenny Ostrom you magnificent human being. I see now what you were trying to say. Sorry for being dense.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help and patience

Comment: I know you found it, but you should get rid of all that junk in main and just call tokenize("1,2,3"). Isolating the problem is a key part of [mcve]. No need to give us the desired input in another comment after the code. Get rid of "getline" and just set the input string directly, so it will demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the loop add:

```
if (temp != "")
{
    tokenVector.push_back(temp);
}
```

For the last element.

```
vector<string> tokenize(string inputString, char delimiter) {

    ...Code...

    for (int i = 0; i < newString.size(); ++i) {
        ...Code...
    }

    if (temp != "") {
        tokenVector.push_back(temp);
    }

    return tokenVector;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Korel. I used basically this fix once I realized what kenny was trying to tell me xD